# Is it possible to forward all http traffic through a different port?

Tags: browser, ports

My ISP is really weird and while they offer a 15 Mb/s plan, it's impossible to upgrade to it because their site always errors when I try to. I've tried contacting them but they don't respond to emails or phone calls. My ISP basically sucks in every way, but it's apart of my apartment so I can't change them.

Anyways, there is a way that I found that I can trick their website into getting me onto the 15 Mb/s plan without paying, but it seems like after a week or so they notice and disconnect me. When I'm 'disconnected', all it does is show their login page for every site I visit. But it seems like even when I'm disconnected, everything else still works fine. I can still torrent at 15 Mb/s and pretty much everything else besides browse the web.

So it makes me think when they 'disconnect' me, they're just blocking port 80 and showing me their log in page. I have no idea if that's actually true or not since I know almost nothing about networks, but is there a way to make it so all of my http traffic goes through a different port? It seems like that way I'd be able to get onto the fast plan, and then even after they do something about it, I wouldn't be affected at all.

Answer (score 1):

Some anonymous proxies use weird port numbers. You can try using HTTP over one of those.

http://www.proxyserverprivacy.com/free-proxy-list.shtml